# XCode How to display extension info in code structure view?

Tags: swift, xcode

In code structure view it is useful to see extension with protocol conformance like in the screenshot you can see that `ViewManager` confirms to `ViewManagerInput, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource.` The problem is that for it to display you have to add `// MARK` annotations manually like that:

```
// MARK: ViewManagerInput

extension ViewManager: ViewManagerInput {
```

I hope there is a way to show the extensions info without the `MARK` part. Is there any way to achieve that?

PS Not sure how the view is called, so I call it code structure view.

[image: extension protocol conformance displayed in code structure view]

Comment: You gotta write _something_ extra, if not the `MARK`. There's no such Xcode setting. You can make your life easier by writing a code snippet or something similar. How does that sound?

Comment: @sweeper sad, the main issue for me is that the `MARK` clutters code